# Matching the first occurrence of each letter in string

Tags: javascript, regex

What I'd like to do is match the first occurrence of two or more letters, so for example, I'd like to highlight A and F from the string below:

```
"ASDFASDFASDFASDF"
```

But only the first `A` and only the first `F`

I've tried:

```
/A{1}F{1}/i
```

But no joy...

Any ideas appreciated...

Comment: What is the purpose? Also, why can't you use something simple, like `.indexOf()`

Comment: I agree on the `indexOf`. If you have no other way, you can give a try to `^[^A]*(A)` when searching for first occurence of `A` (as there is no variable length lookbehind using javascript RegExp). Capturing group will let you know the occurence position in the string.

Comment: Unless you want to do something with the **position of** `A` and `F` in the string, simply `includes` or `indexOf` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are easier approaches like using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Just as an idea, you could use a different approach and not use a regex to find the first occurence, but to reverse the string and then find the last occurence using a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Then use replace with a regex to add your wrapper like `<span>` and then reverse the string again.

Example regexes for last occurrence:

[`(shark|trip)(?!.*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/ppJJHh/1)

[`([A|F])(?!.*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/Wm0CbP/1)

```js
var str1 = "ASDFASDFASDFASDF";
str1 = str1
    .split("").reverse().join("")
    .replace(/([A|F])(?!.*\1)/gim, '>naps/<$1>naps<')
    .split("").reverse().join("");
document.write(str1);

document.write("<br>");

var str2 = "I am on a shark fishing trip, a fishing trip for shark I am on.";
str2 = str2
    .split(" ").reverse().join(" ")
    .replace(/(shark|trip)(?!.*\1)/gim, '<span>$1</span>')
    .split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
document.write(str2);
```

```css
span {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the match you want:

```
/^(a).*?(f)/i
```

- ^ asserts position at start of the string
- .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
- *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

Comment: Only when `F` is always is behind `A`, which almost certainly is not the case.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: https://regex101.com/r/IxkI5p/4 - it matches everything from A to F - but I just need A and F

Comment: Another example... I would like to highlight (wrap around some span tags) the words shark and trip. But only the first instance of each word:

Comment: I am on a shark fishing trip, a fishing trip for shark I am on.

Comment: so words 5 and 7 would be highlighted if you see what I mean?

Comment: Look at the capture groups.